# Get Java files in Directory and all Subdirectories

Tags: java, regex, nio, java-io

I am trying to get all `.java-files` in a `directory` (that is given)  and all its subdirectories . This is what Ive come up:

```
public static void getJavaFiles(Path path) {


    DirectoryStream<Path> stream = null;
    try {

        stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path);
        for (Path entry : stream) {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(entry)) {
                if(entry.getFileName().toString() == "*.java") {
                    System.out.println(entry.getFileName().toString());
                };

            } else if (Files.isDirectory(entry)) {
                getJavaFiles(entry);
            }

        }



    } catch (IOException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("error reading folder %s: %s", path, e.getMessage()), e);

    } finally {
        if(stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }   

}
```

Unfortunately `entry.getFileName().toString() == "*.java"` is not working how I thought it would. I get all the files but how do I get only the `.java` files ?

Comment: You'd have to use `.matches(.*\\.java")`. There are 2 issues with that comparison - the first is that you use the `equals` method to compare strings, and the second is that that string will only match files called "*.java" exactly, not files matching that pattern

Comment: @user what would be the correct way to do it then?

Comment: You just need `if(entry.getFileName().toString().contains(".java"))`. Or, if it must be at the end, `.endsWith(".java")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that was it! Works perfectly. thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh wait, actually not. what about this file: example.java.txt ? This should not be detected

Comment: `.endsWith(".java")` will make sure the string ends with `.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this:

```
if(entry.getFileName().endsWith(".java"))
```

Comment: does this make sure that I only get actual `java` files? Or are there any special cases I have to check?

Comment: No need to check. You will get the actual java file only

Comment: ok thanks. why was it downvoted ..

Comment: the same type of problem was asked earlier in the site. But still I answered. That's why probably. If it worked for you, you can accept the answer. @Chris